# Как научить телеграм-бота пересылать сообщения из телеграм-каналов в чат собеседника и этого бота?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telebot, telegram

Пишу телеграм-бота с помощью библиотеки pyTelegramBotAPI в VS. Хочу научить бота пересылать сообщение из какого-нибудь телеграм-канала в чат бота. Использую метод forward_message, он работает, если пересылать из чата бота в этот же чат. Этот метод активируется при отправке кого-нибудь текстового сообщения. Если я меняю место пересылки сообщения, то при активации метода VS выдаёт ошибку 400 и пишет, что не найден либо чат (канал), из которого пересылается сообщение, либо само пересылаемое сообщение.
Используемый метод:

```
@bot.message_handler()
def rep(message):     
    if message.text == 'keyword':
      bot.forward_message(message.chat.id, @ixbt_official, 15499) #канал и пересылаемое сообщение взяты условно
```

При выполнении выдаётся ошибка [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно это исправить?

Answer (score 0):

Но для работы такого метода надо чтобы бот был добавлен в группу(канал) и имел доступ к сообщениям.

```py
@dp.message_handler(sand_message, content_types=["text"])
async def sand_message(message: types.Message):
    bot_chat_id = # id чата с ботом
    group_id = # id группы откуда надо пересылать новые сообщения
    if message.chat.id != bot_chat_id:
        await bot.forward_message(bot_chat_id, group_id, message.message_id)
```

Сообщение в группе:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пришло от бота:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А как можно добавить бота в публичный канал, если  ты не являешься владельцем?

Comment: Можно просто через кнопку приглашения(вводишь название бота и выбираешь в списке снизу).